# why fast-compare not working but own isEqual function works?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use memo in my script. I dont know why my data rerenders when I use fast-compare (isEqual) and when I use my own function (isEq) then its not rerender. Why ?

```
import isEqual from 'react-fast-compare'

function isEq(prev: IColorItem, next: IColorItem) {
  if(prev.activeColor === next.activeColor) {
    return true;
  }
}

// rerenders

const Item = memo(({ color, index, style, activeColor, onPress }: IColorItem) => {
  console.log('render');
  return (
    <Button style={s.center} onPress={() => onPress(color)}>
      <Text>{color}</Text>
    </Button>
  )
  // @ts-ignore
}, isEqual);

// No rerender
const Item = memo(({ color, index, style, activeColor, onPress }: IColorItem) => {
  console.log('render');
  return (
    <Button style={s.center} onPress={() => onPress(color)}>
      <Text>{color}</Text>
    </Button>
  )
  // @ts-ignore
}, isEq);
```

€:

Item:

```
  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<ColorsType> = ({ item, index }) => (
    <Item
      color={item}
      index={index}
      style={style}
      activeColor={activeColor}
      onPress={onPress}
    />
  )
```

Comment: `react-fast-compare` does a deep check *all* the props, while yours only checks activeColor. So apparently, one of the other props is changing. We'll need to see how you are rendering the `<Item>` to tell you which prop(s) are at fault

Comment: @NicholasTower Hello, thank you for your answer, I have edited my code above you can now see my Item

Comment: I also need to see how `style` and `onPress` are defined. If they are changing, then the `react-fast-compare` version will rerender the component. Yours will ignore the changes, since your function only checks `activeColor`. (`item` and `index` could theoretically be changing too, though i suspect that's not what you're seeing)